# Split a List<string> after a certain line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm reading a file per line using StreamReader and adding each line as an item to a List.

There are two sections in the file, "MMap" and "missionMMap".

Is there a way to split the list after missionMMap and append it to another list?
An alternative could be to directly add any lines after "missionMMap" to List missionMMap directly.

My code:

```
    List<string> MMap = new List<string>();
    List<string> missionMMap = new List<string>();

    public void readFile(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            MMap.Clear();
            using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        MMap.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error!"); }
    }
```

The file looks like this:

```
[MMap]  SpeciesIdx
1       15
[missionMMap]   SpeciesIdx
1               15
```

Thanks in advance.
PS: I appologize for any grammar mistakes.

Comment: How are the sections delimited? Is it just a line with `missionMMap` and then items for that list?

Comment: Use one bool variable when the line is equal to your value make it true. If the value is true start adding in the other list.

Comment: The different sections are defined by containing MMap for the first one at the first line and missionMMap for the second, the rest are just numbers.

I tried using a bool, however the `while` statement would reset the bool as the rest of the section is numbers.

Comment: `Karim` to help others out here do the following
`1` show a single line example of the file you are parsing / reading` `2` explain what the Delimeter is also you can use one List<T> to hold the data based on properly Splitting the line are you familiar with the `Split` function

Comment: I edited the question, thanks for your tips DJ KRAZE, and no I am not familiar with the Split function.

On a side note: What did I do wrong to have my question recieve negative feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the string `[missionMMap]` to break up the parts in the file something like this should work out.

```
using(StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line;
    bool isMissionMMap = false;

    while((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            if(!isMissionMMap && line.StartsWith("[missionMMap]")) // Short circuit early if the missionMMap portion has already been entered
            {
                isMissionMMap = true;
                continue; //Ignore this line of text as it is more than likely useless
            }

            if(isMissionMMap)
            {
                missionMMap.Add(line);
            }
            else
            {
                MMap.Add(line)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: You can replace the last `if/else` statement with a pretty funky ternary operator if you want. I'm not going to recommend it because it isn't that readable, I am just adding it because I find it cool.

```
(isMissionMMap ? missionMMap : MMap).Add(line);
```

Again, I wouldn't use it but it is cool that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The nested `if`'s are not pretty, but this will work.

```
List<string> MMap = new List<string>();
List<string> missionMMap = new List<string>();

public void readFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        MMap.Clear();

        // This technically doesn't need to be initialized here, but better safe...
        bool readingMMap = true;

        using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    if(line.StartsWith("[MMap]"))
                    {
                        readingMMap = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.StartsWith("[missionMMap]"))
                    {
                        readingMMap = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(readingMMap)
                            MMap.Add(line);
                        else
                            missionMap.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error!"); }
}
```